# My mac app does not change its language even after changing the Development Region on Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, localization

I'm developing a mac app and I could not change the development language even though I changed the parameter on `project.pbxproj`.

```
        developmentRegion = en;
        hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
        knownRegions = (
            en,
            Base,
            "zh-Hans",
            "zh-Hant",
            ko,
            ja,
        );
```

However, the app always runs with Japanese localization. The Xcode shows that English is the current development language and I made sure I have all the English's localization file on the project.

I also tried Chinese and Korean but it still did not change from Japanese. I just changed to use Base language today and everything started to not work properly...

So how can I change it to any language but Japanese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS app, you change the localization language from *Edit Scheme* -> *Run* -> *App Language*, which is located under the app name on the status bar. It is irrelevant to change the content on *project.pbxproj*.

[image]

---

#### UPDATE

Hmmm.. this seems to not work in French for some reasons. But it works in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.